# Custom Error Handling in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I've tried implementing the answer listed here: [Properly handling 404s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/620559) which came from this blog post: [Real World Error Handling](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shay/archive/2009/03/06/real-world-error-hadnling-in-asp-net-mvc-rc2.aspx)

All I get is a blank page.  I step through the debugger and I see the Exception catch, the ErrorController method get called and the return of the View execute, but then I don't see anything in the web browser.  Firebug tells me I got back a 0 byte response from the server and the URL is not changed to the ErrorController.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,  I've found the answer.  Copy and Paste error from the example.  My view is called Error, the examples have it called Index.